# Why L belongs to the dual space $H^{-1}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, duality-theorems

I'm studying pde using Evans book. In chapter 6 he introduces second order partial differential operators for example :

$L= \sum{D_i(a_{ij}D_j(u))+\sum{b_iD_i(u)+cu}}$

I can't understand why $L \in H^{-1}$, the dual space of $H_0^1$, i'm struggling beacuase to me it would require that $u$ must have 2 derivaties so $u \in H^2$ to be well define.
Am I missing something? 
Thanks.

Comment: There are more concepts of derivative than the one you are thinking of. You should review the definition of $H^{-1}$ to see why every $L^2$ function has a derivative that is an element of $H^{-1}$.

Comment: Can you give me a refernce please?